# Evaluating anonymous function(s) within switch statement

Tags: r, switch-statement, anonymous-function

Say I have a code like this:

```
tmp <- switch("b",
              a = print("foo"),
              b = function() paste("I want to evaluate this one!"),
              stop("say what now?")
)
```

Now, if I type `tmp` I get an unevaluated function, so I have to do add a pair of brackets afterwards in order to evaluate it:

```
tmp
## function() paste("I want to evaluate this one!")
tmp()
## [1] "I want to evaluate this one!"
```

Of course, I can predefine this function and pass it within `switch` (in that case it's not anonymous), but I want to know if it's possible and/or reasonable to evaluate anonymous function within `switch` statement.

Comment: I'm struggling to see why `b` can't just be `paste("I want to evaluate this one!")`, i.e. get R to evaluate that statement in order to supply a returned object that will get passed to `tmp`? I didn't get why you would want to do this if the end result is to have the evaluated result in `tmp`? Can you provide more info or explanation?

Comment: AFAIK this is the default behavior (print object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose one could arrange for `do.call()` to call the anonymous function:

```
tmp <- switch("b",
              a = print("foo"),
              b = do.call(function() paste("I want to evaluate this one!"), 
                          list()),
              stop("say what now?")
)
```

e.g.:

```
> tmp
[1] "I want to evaluate this one!"
```

---

**Edit**
A simpler version of the above is:

```
tmp <- switch("b",
              a = print("foo"),
              b = (function() paste("I want to evaluate this one!"))(),
              stop("say what now?")
)
```

So the anonymous function is created in the first set of parentheses and the resulting function is called by appending the second set of `()`.

---

But it seems cleaner to me to turn the anonymous function into a named function and call it:

```
foo <- function() paste("I want to evaluate this one!")
tmp <- switch("b",
              a = print("foo"),
              b = foo(),
              stop("say what now?")
)
```

Which has the same end result:

```
> tmp
[1] "I want to evaluate this one!"
```

If this is all within a function, `foo()` could be defined inline so it only exists during the execution of the outer function call.

Comment: +1 for this one! I assumed that the solution is going to be quite simple and extremely obvious... And I especially like the `(tmp)()` detail... =)

Answer (score 1):

From what I recall, writing your object (be that data.frame, a list or as in your case, a function) without braces evokes `print()`.

Obviously:

```
> class(tmp())
[1] "character"
> class(tmp)
[1] "function"
```

Comment: I'm not sure this was what @aL3xa was getting at. I understood the Q to mean how do I get the anonymous, inline function get evaluated and called such that `tmp` returns what `tmp()` currently does in the code shown in the Q. He actually wants `tmp` to hold the **result** of calling that anonymous function.

Comment: Sure thing, but I want to evaluate function... Gavin got it... =)

Answer (score 1):

As Roman said, you get a function returned. If you want the result of a function, then just put the function (in your case, drop the `function()` ). If you want a combination of different functions, put it between brackets :

```
tmp <- switch("b",
              a = print("foo"),
              b = {
                    x <- paste("I want to evaluate this one!")
                    x <- paste(x,sample(1:10,1))
                    print(x)
              },
              stop("say what now?")
)
```

But you should be aware that you only keep the result, so you'll always have the same result from `sample`.